# Updating a Mysql database using an external variable

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update (not insert) a python variable into a Mysql database. Searches show me many examples of the UPDATE being set to a constant,and this works for me: fragment

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE enviromental SET temp = 10  WHERE room = 'Hot Water Tank A'")

mydb.commit()
```

works well,

but,

```
print (hot_water_temp)

mycursor.execute("UPDATE enviromental SET temp = hot_water_temp  WHERE room = 'Hot Water Tank A'")

mydb.commit()
```

gives me:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/srv/nfs/mysqlconnector.py", line 20, in 
mycursor.execute("UPDATE enviromental SET temp = hot_water_temp  WHERE room = 'Hot Water Tank A'")
File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'hot_water_temp' in 'field list'

```
Is my python variable just not seen inside the SQL statement? I not, how can I get it into the statement?

This must be a pretty common thing to want to do, but none of my searches gave me even a hint of how this should be done

Regards
```

Comment: Read the docs, especially about the `params` parameter: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: I used the link to modify to:                                                                                   updatedata = (
  "UPDATE enviromental SET temp = %s WHERE room = %s"
  "VALUES (%s, %s)"
)
data = (hot_water_temp, 'Hot Water Tank A')
mycursor.execute(updatedata, data)                                                                                                              But the error now is now that there are not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Comment: `UPDATE` does not take a `VALUES` clause. The number of parameters in your `data` list must be the same as the number of `%s` placeholders in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally puzzled this out, but the linked documentation was of little use, as like most other posted information, it references the INSERT, rather than UPDATE. It was essential to use two variables, looking like this:

sql_update_query = """UPDATE enviromental SET temp = %s WHERE room = %s"""

input_data = (hot_water_temp, 'Hot Water Tank A')

mycursor.execute(sql_update_query, input_data)

I sill don't quite understand what is going on, but this fragment works.